# SpringBoot : Autowired dependency in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to develop a springboot application from scratch. As i am new to springboot i am not able to add autowired annotation ... seems like i am missing some dependency in pom.xml

here are the scenario

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>firstprogram</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <name>firstprogram Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>firstprogram</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

if i am trying to add dependency with spring mvc. it is giving warning like spring boot is already adding those dependency.

Comment: Could you add more code here so that easy to locate the issue? Dependency wise  fine.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: try using https://start.spring.io/ for a starter project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your service is annotated with the class @Component or @Service, and then when you use the service in another class, add the tag @Autowired to the class.

Also maybe @ComponentScan